# Problem using redis-clojure with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, redis, leiningen

Hey, I'm new to Clojure and Leiningen and a bit stuck. I've managed to setup a project with Leiningen. I'm able to compile it into an uberjar and run the `repl`. I've also managed to load a dependency named `aleph` to run a simple concurrent webserver.

The next step for me is to use `redis-clojure` to access redis. But here I'm stuck. This is my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject alpha "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Just an alpha test script"
  :main alpha.core
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [aleph, "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [redis-clojure "1.2.4"]])
```

And here is my `core.clj`: Note that I only added the line `(:requre redis)` according to the example from redis-clojure.

```
(ns alpha.core
  (:require redis)
  (:gen-class))

(use `aleph.core 'aleph.http)

(defn alpha [channel request]
  (let [] (enqueue-and-close channel
                     {:status 200
                      :header {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
                      :body "Hello Clojure World!"}))
          (println (str request)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (start-http-server alpha {:port 9292}))
```

When I try to run `lein repl` this happens:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate redis__init.class or redis.clj on classpath:  (core.clj:1)
```

Yes, I have run `lein deps` and the redis-clojure jar is available in my `lib` directory. I'm probably missing something trivial, but I've been at this issue for a few hours now and not getting any closer to a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Namespace **redis** does not exist. I suppose you need

```
(:require [redis.core :as redis])
```

A way to check for available namespaces:

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.find-namespaces)
(filter #(.startsWith (str %) "redis") (find-namespaces-on-classpath))
```

Comment: That's the one. How did you figure that out? I mean, how could I have found out myself?

Comment: You can also peek in the jar file. If you use Emacs, open the jar like a normal file and see its contents. Otherwise use "jar -tf lib/redis-clojure-1.2.4.jar" on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

This works with more current versions of Clojure, in this example it finds the names of all namespaces that contains the sub string "jdbc":

```
(map str
  (filter
    #(> (.indexOf (str %) "jdbc") -1)
    (all-ns)))
```

The result is a sequence, in example:

```
=> 
("clojure.java.jdbc")
```